# the page does not display pictures

Tags: magento-2.1

I installed paid template ethan on Magento 2.1.1 and imported a ready full demo database.

Unfortunately, when I imported full demo the database, the page stopped displaying correctly. also administrative panel is working correctly

Only the main banner is displayed. in the attachment a screenshot of the entire page.

Here is error code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function unserialize() on null in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-swatches\Helper\Data.php:174 Stack trace: #0 F:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-swatches\Helper\Data.php(530): Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data->populateAdditionalDataEavAttribute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor)) #1 F:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-swatches\Model\Plugin\Configurable.php(62): Magento\Swatches\Helper\Data->isVisualSwatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor)) #2 F:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(152): Magento\Swatches\Model\Plugin\Configurable->afterGetUsedProductCollection(Object(Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor), Object(Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Product\Collection\Interceptor)) #3 F:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\var\generation\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-swatches\Helper\Data.php on line 174
```

[image]

Comment: Please check the right version of theme to be installed. The behavior of error provided by you seems like wrong version of Magento. There are some updates in serialization at Magento2.2.x versions.

Comment: Can you switch theme to Luma and check so we can sure that this is the theme issue or php version issue

Comment: I think this is a template problem. I installed the freshly bought template and everything worked fine.  A ready database with products, descriptions, etc. was attached to the template. When I imported it, problems began.